# (Discord.py) Send the same message to all guilds

Tags: python, python-3.x, discord.py

I'm developing a small bot for a few groups of friends that sends the same message at a specific time every Friday using Cron.

It has a "CHANNEL_ID" variable with the channel ID to send the message in, but this only works with a specific guild.

Is there any way to send the same message to multiple IDs, like a list or an array?

The method to send the message in the first text channel available to the bot in the guild can't work, because it depends from server to server.

Comment: Hi Gabriel, please see [ask]

Comment: so do you have to list of channel id where to send?

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

The nearest example of what you want seems like this

```
async def SendMsgAll(self, ctx):
    count = 0
    for guild in self.client.guilds:
        channel_in_guild = []
        for channel in guild.text_channels:
            channel_in_guild.append(channel)
    send_channel = channel_in_guild[count]
    try:
        await send_channel.send("test")
    except:
        count += 1
```

Comment: the problem is that it looks like it'd try sending the message in ALL the channels, while I want it to send it in one specific channel per server. also, what happens if the channel it tries sending a message in is a restricted one and he doesn't have permissions for it?

Comment: I've updated like what you want. Is this answer your question? @Gabriel

Comment: close, but not quite, as that sends messages to all channels, and what I planned was that it sends the message only in a specific channel, like "General", but it's ok since I added the IDs to an array manually because it's a small bot.